# Using Android internal API to turn on GPS

Tags: android, gps

Is there any hidden (internal) API function for turning on/off the GPS? Is it a valid solution (legally and safely) to use android internal API's? If it is not valid, how can I obtain a license/signature for using those API's?

**I have already tried the methods using SDK/NDK and I understood that it is not possible to turn GPS on with the SDK/NDK (I know that we can bring up the settings screen). I want to know whether there is any hidden/internal API's for doing that. Also I am not interested in using any vulnerabilities in Android as a solution.**

Comment: The ability to turn on a location service without the user's explicit consent would be somewhat questionable. Whilst I'm not aware of any way to do this how you ask, I'd question whether or not you should/would do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need root privileges. Mandatory. Period.

And yes there is API to enable/disable GPS. But the application must receive SuperAdmin privileges. To obtain it either root or custom ROM required.

Sample: https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden API for controlling the GPS. There is no valid solution.

(Like you mentioned), the correct thing to do is ask the user to turn it on. If an app could override the users option, there would be no point in it being an option and this would be a huge security rick.

If the user chooses to keep the GPS off then your apps should do the same thing it would do if the GPS was on but couldn't get a lock. Not respecting their wished to keep it off would be malicious even if you don't plan on doing anything morally wrong with the data.

If you have some client that wants their employees to not be able to turn off the GPS, then you need to give them phones with custom roms.

If you are trying to make a security app that reports location you can use wifi location and last known location too in addition to GPS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I have one more doubt. How the android control panel is turning on the GPS, it is also an activity right?

Comment: its built into the rom. If you need more control over the GPS you need to make a custom rom for a phone. You won't be able to make an app that can be published on google play that takes control over GPS

Comment: Well. Actually you can publish GPS controllers and quite a lot of a kind already published. But 'root' is mandatory.

Comment: Oh I forgot about root